# ROS Answers SE migration: topic question

Tags: ros, nodes, topics, messages, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ubuntu 16.04 ROS kinetic

as per http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingTopics, i have listed my verbose details on topics in use rn:

```
~$ rostopic list -v

Published topics:
 * /turtle1/color_sensor [turtlesim/Color] 1 publisher
 * /turtle1/cmd_vel [geometry_msgs/Twist] 1 publisher
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log] 4 publishers
 * /rosout_agg [rosgraph_msgs/Log] 1 publisher
 * /turtle1/pose [turtlesim/Pose] 1 publisher

Subscribed topics:
 * /turtle1/cmd_vel [geometry_msgs/Twist] 2 subscribers
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log] 1 subscriber
 * /statistics [rosgraph_msgs/TopicStatistics] 1 subscriber
```

then I tried `$ rostopic list -p` to see the list of publishers.

```
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/turtle1/cmd_vel
/turtle1/color_sensor
/turtle1/pose
```

1. I did not expect to see the names of topics here because I did not understand that the publishers and subscribers themselves are actually the topics. I would have thought that the pubs and subs would just be nodes. Can someone explain why this is?
2. are all of these topics only topics or can a topic also be a node or a message?
3. just to check my understanding, is this right? a topic recieves a message from a node and gives it to a different node? does it sometimes give it to a different topic like could it be a recursive path through many things or like a function in algebra where you may have one message and one topic goes to more than one node ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269613/topic-question/) by [moonspacedancer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31680/moonspacedancer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2017-08-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-25**:
This question would be easier to read (and answer) if you use the Preformat Text (`101010`) button on the commands that you ran and the terminal output.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-25**:
@binarybabe: have you read the [Concepts](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Concepts) page on the wiki? That should answer some of your questions. Also, I'll reiterate my advise from #q269540 to pick up a book or two about ROS.

**Comment by [moonspacedancer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31680/moonspacedancer/) on 2017-08-26**:
rosout is a node and /rosout is also a topic. that clears a lot up for me actually. thank you

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-26**:
I'm not understanding this. Is this an answer to your question or a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, based on your answer (comment?) a node is *not* also a topic (if I understand you correctly). There is a node named `/rosout` and a topic with the name `/rosout`. If you run `rostopic info /rosout` you'll see that the node `/rosout` is not publishing to the topic `/rosout`:

```
Type: rosgraph_msgs/Log

Publishers: 
 * /turtlesim (http://jayess:55350/)

Subscribers: 
 * /rosout (http://jayess:38176/)
```

I'm not sure what node(s) you were running for your question so I am using the `turtlesim_node` here because it looks to be pretty similar.

With `turtlesim_node` running, if i run `rostopic list -v` I get the following output:

```
Published topics:
 * /turtle1/color_sensor [turtlesim/Color] 1 publisher
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log] 1 publisher
 * /rosout_agg [rosgraph_msgs/Log] 1 publisher
 * /turtle1/pose [turtlesim/Pose] 1 publisher

Subscribed topics:
 * /turtle1/cmd_vel [geometry_msgs/Twist] 1 subscriber
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log] 1 subscriber
```

This shows the names of the topics such as `/turtle1/color_sensor`, the message type `turtlesim/Color`, and how many publishers `1 publisher` listed under the section labeled `Published topics`. It's similar for the subscribers.

Now, if I run `rostopic list`, I get the following output:

```
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/turtle1/cmd_vel
/turtle1/color_sensor
/turtle1/pose
```

and if I run `rostopic list -p`, I get the following output:

```
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/turtle1/color_sensor
/turtle1/pose
```

The difference between the two commands (as far as I know) is that `rostopic list` shows *all* topics and `rostopic list -p` shows only the topics that are currently being published. Notice with the last command that the `/turtle1/cmd_vel` isn't shown. This is because nothing is publishing to it. The `turtlesim_node` is subscribed to it, that's why it's listed with `rostopic list`. You can prove this by running `rostopic info /turtle1/cmd_vel`:

```
Type: geometry_msgs/Twist

Publishers: None

Subscribers: 
 * /turtlesim (http://jayess:55350/)
```

So, don't get confused when nodes and topics have the same name, they are ***completely different entities*** but can have the same name without affecting anything (except to sometimes confuse people). Like @gvdhoorn suggested, you should pick up some books on ROS (and read more of the wiki) to help clarify some of these concepts.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [moonspacedancer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31680/moonspacedancer/) on 2017-08-28**:
Thank you!! very in depth answer. I see now that the rosout comes as a node and as a topic and that's what was confusing me